# Is this citation for reference correct? (APA 7th edition)

Tags: research-process, citations, citation-style

Is the citation in APA 7th edition format correct for [this technical report](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA218928.pdf)?

Citation:
Servan-Schreiber, D., Cleeremans, A., & McClelland, J. L. (1988). *Encoding sequential structure in simple recurrent networks.* Carnegie Mellon University, Computer Science Department.

The only part I'm not sure about is whether the "Carnegie Mellon University, Computer Science Department" is correct or not as I'm not sure if that's the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the technical report number.

Going by APA 7 guide: [10.4: Report and gray literature (with Individual Authors References)](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/report-individual-authors-references), you should be looking at:

Servan-Schreiber, D., Cleeremans, A., & McClelland, J. L. (1988). ServaEncoding sequential structure in simple recurrent networks (Technical Report: CMU-CS-88-183). Carnegie Mellon University, Computer Science Department.

NB: CMU-CS-88-183 is not archived on Carnegie-Mellon University, [Computer Science Dept Technical Reports Collection site](http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/cs.html).

If your [source is PDF from DTIC (DEFENSE TECHNICAL INFORMATION CENTER)](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA218928), your year will be 1989, report # will be ADA218928 and URL will be https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA218928
Or maybe (though not proper):
https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA218928.pdf

You might want to also take a look at

- UMGC [APA 7th Edition Citation Examples: Technical + Research Reports](https://libguides.umgc.edu/c.php?g=1003870&p=7270670)
- Victoria University Australia [APA 7th Referencing: Reports & Grey Literature](https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/apa-referencing/7ReportsGreyLiterature)